# Error : Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

**I am trying to return multiple sessions that belongs to the same case** 

**Route in file routes.php:**

```
Route::get('company/case/{case_id}/session/', ['before' => 'auth|can:view_all_sessions*view_own_sessions', 'uses' => 'SessionController@index', 'as' => 'company.session.index']);
```

**Controller :: SessionController.php:**

```
    public function index($case_id) {
    $case = LawCase::findOrFail($case_id);

    $sessions = $case->sessions()->orderBy(Input::get('field', 'date'), Input::get('sort', 'desc'))
        ->paginate(20);

    $data = [
        'sessions' => $sessions,
        'form' => null,
        'title' => trans('links.sessions'),
        'case' => $case,
        'case_id' => $case_id
    ];

    $this->layout->section = View::make('session.index', $data);
}
```

**Model class :: LawSession.php:**

```
    public function lawcase() {
    return $this->belongsTo(LawCase::class, 'case_id');
}
```

**Model class :: LawCase.php:**

```
public function sessions() {
    return $this->hasMany(LawSession::class, 'case_id');
}
```

And I got this Error :

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
dd($case->getRelations());
```

Do you see your relation there? If yes, do:

```
dd($case->sessions);
```

Does it return related data?

If this doesn't help find the issue please share the full stack trace. It's hard to guess the solution without logs.

You can find logs in:

```
/storage/logs/laravel.php
```

Comment: even if , i return it and gave the same error
all sessions are found and true but
dd($case->getRelations()); gives :::array (size=0)  empty

Comment: Are you sure you have ``law_sessions`` table in the database with related data already?

Comment: Sure ,all database tables are correct and tested before

Comment: Again, please share full log or recent stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Just modify this line in SessionController.php

`$sessions = $case->sessions->orderBy(Input::get('field', 'date'), Input::get('sort', 'desc'))->paginate(20);`

and make there's relation record exist in database.

Comment: it gave :
Call to undefined method

Comment: it can not see this method